# Remove multiple lines & Display single line after one row

Tags: html, css

we can see 2 rows in below image we have 5-6 horizontal lines after one row.

[image]

I want to hide all those lines & want to display single line after one row as like below

[image]

```
#shopping-cart-table .a-center {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#cart2 {
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}

.cart-table thead th, .cart-table tbody td {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your existing css to below css.

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1224px){
.cart thead {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 13px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
.cart thead {
    background: #fff url("../images/product_view_line.png") no-repeat scroll 0 31px / 1250px 1px;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 13px !important;
}
```

Comment: it removed all horizontal lines, thats fine please help me to add one line as in 2nd image